# What does Reachability really mean in iOS?

Tags: ios, reachability

I have this code in my app:

```
-(void)reachAlert:(Reachability*)currentReach {

    if(currentReach == hostReach) {
        //Make sure we have internet connectivity
        //UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Excellent" message:@"Host Reached" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        //[internetAlert show];
        [[SDSyncEngine sharedEngine] startSync];


    }
    /**
     if(currentReach == internetReach) {
     //Make sure we have internet connectivity
     UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Good"
     message:@"Internet"
     delegate:self
     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
     otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
     [internetAlert show];
     }
     **/
    if(currentReach == wifiReach) {
        //Make sure we have internet connectivity
        UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bad News"
                                                                message:@"Only wifi"
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [internetAlert show];
    }
    [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"reachAlert"];


}
```

As you can see I commented out internetReach because I figured, whats more important is that we have hostReach.  Thus by default we must have internet reach.  I also commented out the hostReach alert only because I only want to alert the user in case of NO internet connectivity.

However when testing the app on wifi, i get the bad news only wifi message.  Why doesnt it give the hostReach alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reachability is really not ideal for displaying error messages. Ideally you should show an error message when the connection you are trying to use fails, for example NSURLConnection returning a -1009 error.

Comment: ok, i got it...so basically just pop up the alertview in case the connection fails, right?

Comment: Yes, error 1009 means you can't connect. You could of course get other errors so you should act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but I found this somewhere and decided it was a much better solution to the problem -- although someone would likely argue about it:

```
- (void) verifyInternetConnection
{
    NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://youtube.com"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
    if (!data)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Required" message:@"This device is not currently connected to the Internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        alert.tag = 1;
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good simple approach but I will point out (perhaps very obviously) that you should not use a url with large content such as youtube. Instead, craft a URL that will respond back with a bare minimum of known data.

Comment: That's not a good approach, because it'll lock the main thread until the data is downloaded from the internet. That'll make your app seem freezed.

Comment: Youtube is not only a bad example from the data size but simply because if you're trying to test this from behind a firewall (ie: I'm on my wifi at my job) and youtube happens to be blocked you get a false negative.

Comment: In my case, I'm wanting to make sure youtube is reachable.  But any URL can be used that fits one's needs.  The best, of course, is the URL you're trying to reach (which was the reason I used youtube).  Google.com is a good generic choice but others could be found with less data.  Good point on blocking main thread though.